# Two source diode protection

Tags: diodes

I need to protect the 12.8v regulator from the 14.5v battery.

Do I try to just reduce the battery voltage below 21.8V with a bunch of diodes? 
Do I just put one diode protecting against current flow into the regulator output? 
Do I do both? 
The load operates on 6-36V, and 30w.

The reason I put several diodes in the last option is this. If both the sources are connected I would like the load to take power from the regulator instead of the battery. I thought with multiple diodes in there it would take from the regulator instead of the battery. Am I right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsmAka.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: The long and the short]

Need to protect the regulator from burning. Which option is correct?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, unless you post a larger image with a proper schematic (@brhans' recommendation is right, use the built-in schematic editor), AND explain what you've considered so far *as text in your question* (not as a comment).

Comment: Oh yeah the picture didn't work out right.  I will post a schematic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voltage sources in parallel?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278290/voltage-sources-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first 2 options won't work.
Both of them will allow your regulator to be 'back-fed', which is usually not a good thing.
The other 2 will prevent the regulator from being back-fed.
If your load doesn't mind the higher voltage then the extra 3 diodes in option #4 are not all necessary, but you'll probably want to keep one of them unless you intend for your regulator to charge the battery too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I put several diodes in the last option is this. If both the sources are connected I would like the load to take power from the regulator instead of the battery. I thought with multiple diodes in there it would take from the regulator instead of the battery. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah - it's less than ideal because you'll waste a little of your battery's energy in the extra diodes, but it will function as you're planning.